# Print string in fixed format by Python code

Tags: python

I want to print a very large string or array in fixed format in order to compare with data file. Here are my string and python code:

```
import re

string1 ='2222//000000'
string2 = '-0.0000023   0.0000008   0.0000001   0.9716336  -0.1052695  -0.0000001  -0.0000002   0.0000007  -0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1316705   0.1175425  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000001 \
            0.0000000  -0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000001   0.0106146   0.1165349'

split = re.findall(r'(?:\b|-)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string2)

for i in range (3):
    print  "{0:<18}".format( string1 ),
    for j in range ( len(split) ):
        print "{0:<10}".format(split[j]),
        if j != 0 and j%9 == 0:
            print "\n", "{0:<18}".format("      " ),
    print  "\n"
```

But this print out as follows:

```
2222//000000       -0.0000023 0.0000008  0.0000001  0.9716336  -0.1052695 -0.0000001 -0.0000002 0.0000007  -0.0000000 0.0000000  
                   0.0000000  0.1316705  0.1175425  -0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  
                   0.0000000  0.0000003  0.0000000  -0.0000001 -0.0000000 0.0000000  -0.0000000 0.0000001  0.0000000  
                   -0.0000003 0.0000000  -0.0000000 -0.0000001 -0.0000001 0.0106146  0.1165349
```

The desired format I expect:

```
2222//000000          -0.0000023   0.0000008   0.0000001   0.9716336  -0.1052695  -0.0000001  -0.0000002   0.0000007  -0.0000000
                       0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1316705   0.1175425  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
                       0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000001
                       0.0000000  -0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000001   0.0106146   0.1165349
```

Each line has nine elements of string2, and the elements aligned with the dot.

Comment: is this python 2?

Comment: Try a multiline string: `"""your string"""`

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: @Alec No need to ask. It is Python 2. The `print` statement would be a syntax error in Python 3.

Comment: I asked because of the print... haven’t seen python 2 in ages

Answer (score 1):

With the following code:

```
string1 ='2222//000000'

string2 = '-0.0000023   0.0000008   0.0000001   0.9716336  -0.1052695  -0.0000001  -0.0000002   0.0000007  -0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1316705   0.1175425  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000001 \
            0.0000000  -0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000001   0.0106146   0.1165349'

split = re.findall(r'(?:\b|-)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string2)

print  split

for i in range (3):
    print  "{0:<18}".format( string1 ),
    for j in range ( len(split) ):
        print "{0:<12}".format(split[j]),
        if  (j+1) >= 9 and (j+1)%9 == 0:
            print "\n", "{0:<18}".format("      " ),
    print  "\n"
```

I can get like this:

```
2222//000000       -0.0000023   0.0000008    0.0000001    0.9716336    -0.1052695   -0.0000001   -0.0000002   0.0000007    -0.0000000   
                   0.0000000    0.0000000    0.1316705    0.1175425    -0.0000000   0.0000000    0.0000000    0.0000000    0.0000000    
                   0.0000000    0.0000000    0.0000003    0.0000000    -0.0000001   -0.0000000   0.0000000    -0.0000000   0.0000001    
                   0.0000000    -0.0000003   0.0000000    -0.0000000   -0.0000001   -0.0000001   0.0106146    0.1165349
```

It will be perfect, if anyone can help on aligning the string elements by dot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re

string1 ='2222//000000'
string2 = '-0.0000023   0.0000008   0.0000001   0.9716336  -0.1052695  -0.0000001  -0.0000002   0.0000007  -0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1316705   0.1175425  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000 \
            0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000001 \
            0.0000000  -0.0000003   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000001  -0.0000001   0.0106146   0.1165349'

split = re.findall(r'(?:\b|-)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string2)
print string1,
for j in range ( len(split) ):
    print("{0:<7}".format(split[j])),
    if j%9 == 0:
        print("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the magic line, "if j%9 == 0", this makes the code better.

Comment: I figure out one improved code as posted, but still not perfectly align by dot of each elements

Comment: add another condition to check if the number is negative remove an extra space in the format statement